# Does Romulan culture recognize the Katra?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-enterprise

As an off-shoot of the Vulcan race, I'm assuming that they also have a Katra(?). I'm wondering if the Romulans ever try to hold onto a deceased person's Katra. I know life is cheap to them, but I had to ask and see if anyone knows the answer.

**Do they actually care enough about anyone to hold on to a Katra, and for that matter, since they're so untrusting, would any of them try to put their Katra into someone else at the point of death?**

Comment: Answering as a comment because I can't source it but my inclination would be to say either no or that, if they do, what the don't have are the mental adepts capable of extracting it at the time of death.  If Romulans have Vulcan-like mental capabilities it has not been established during the run of the franchise.  (Have not seen ST:D so can't comment on any revelations from that source.)

Comment: Thank you, Emsley Wyatt. Makes perfect sense to me. I feel dumb for not considering that.

Comment: The [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Katra) entry is inconclusive. I suspect this cannot be answered from canon sources.

Comment: The Romulans left Vulcan during the period when Katra philosophy and mental control were being experimented with. Since we know that they had little interest in developing mental control of their emotions, it's unlikely that they were especially interested in high-level Vulcan experimental psychology.

Comment: Honestly, we don't know enough about what a katra really is to answer this until someone does a canonical story about it. The way it's described, I would argue that every sentient being has a katra...the real question is whether it can be extracted and transferred. Not being telepaths, humans and Romulans can't do this themselves, although I suppose a Vulcan could, at the moment of death, extract their katra for them instead--that is, a pull rather than a push.

Comment: @AlFleming we need some clarification. Your question's title is not the same as what the question itself is asking.

Comment: I deleted my first answer because of the new title - but I'm pretty sure the new title just begs the answer "no". I'm gonna post it and see how many downvotes I get.

Comment: to be honest, I'm not looking for rep here, I'm just trying to answer the question honestly - and it's pretty simple. Katra is a Vulcan thing, not Romulan

Comment: @LevenTrek The title _"Do Romulans have a Katra care?"_ is a bit weird sounding but I'm not sure what a better one would be, do you want to edit it to better match the question body seeing as you have answered?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think there's a way this question can be asked that doesn't make it a Yes or No.

Comment: Personally, I'm a "the more info, the better" kinda guy, so I'd be fine with seeing it posted both ways.

Comment: @LevenTrek - I think it's reasonable, since they're both highly related, to ask them both at the same time.

Comment: @Valorum, we can't ask the two questions simultaneously because they are opposites. If the question is "Do Romulans have a Katra?", the answer is Yes. If the question is "Do Romulans care about the Katra?", the answer is No. It's not possible to answer both questions with a single answer.

Comment: @LevenTrek - One would answer the other

Comment: @Valorum, you're absolutely right. but we have to pick one of the two. we can't keep changing the question in ways that change the answer (see past edits)

Comment: Romulans are born with a katra, but have it surgically removed before their first birthday.

Comment: @Valorum, I really thought the first edit made the title match the rest of the question - it's not "do they have one", it's "do they recognize/use it". Is there a reason you reverted that change to the title?

Comment: @LevenTrek - Because the title made no sense. Not just in the context of the question, but it was literally nonsensical.

Comment: @Valorum, you're right, "do they have katra care" was super weird, but it was still closer to what the question was asking. I'm going to try to fix it without making it nonsensical - I hope you approve

Comment: @LevenTrek - Or you could just stop fiddling with it. You'll go blind

Comment: @Valorum too late :-). I'm not trying to be difficult, and honestly, I love your answer. I still disagree though, and I'm about to edit my "Yes" answer with some additional evidence

Comment: This is such a cool topic, but the question phrasing makes it a juggling act. I really just wish we could "split" it, but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2):

**All living beings have a Katra.**

But @Valorum's answer is correct - there's no evidence that Romulans are aware of it, or can "use" it.

---

In *Star Trek: Discovery*  S01E06, Lieutenant Stamets explains his understanding of the Katra concept:

> STAMETS: I got to say, this Katra stuff is way cool. An uncharted superhighway connecting ***all*** of conciousness and life?

Comment: The topic is not 'Does the Romulans have Katra?' but 'Do they care about it?'

Comment: Then let's edit the title. Because it very literally says "Do the Romulans have a Katra". If the question is "Do they care about it", then that should be the title.

Answer (score 2):

### Main Canon

There's no specific confirmation in any of the TV shows, films or official novelisations whether (or not) Romulans have a Katra. Their general [lack of telepathic abilities](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Romulan#Apocrypha) would *suggest* that they don't have the ability to use them to transfer knowledge, but then again, who knows what goes on at the highest echelons of Romulan society or behind the closed doors of the Tal Shiar...?

### EU Canon

We have a couple of Extended Universe sources that indicate that Romulans almost certainly **don't** have Katras, or at the very least if they do, then they're entirely unable to do anything useful with them;

In *[Starfleet Academy #15 - T'Priell Revealed, Part II of III](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/star-trek-starfleet-academy-15-tpriell-revealed-pa/4000-44629/)* we see a Romulan archaeologist and specialist in proto-Romulan cultures **who doesn't know what a Katra is, nor how to use one**. This seems proof-positive that Katras aren't a thing in Romulan society.

[image]

In [TOS: The Lost Years](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Lost_Years) we find that the teachings of the '*mind-lords*' (instrumental in allowing the Vulcans to learn how to control and share Katras) never made it to Romulus when the early Romulans split from the Vulcans. It would appear that their telepathic powers are crude and ill-formed in comparison and that the level of *mental sophistication* required to share a Katra would be well beyond them.

> “When the Romulans separated from the Vulcans,” Spock continued, “none
> of the old High Masters went with them. Those on Vulcan, after Zakal’s
> death, chose to align themselves with Surak. The discipline underwent
> a radical change in philosophy. The path of Kolinahr still harnesses
> great mental powers—but, for the sake of peace, applies them inward,
> to the control of one’s mind and emotions, rather than using them to
> control individuals and the outer environment.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: The Lost Years](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Lost_Years)</sup></sub>

Comment: I love this answer and all the detail - but I don't agree. The Katra is not a Vulcan invention, it's a natural part of living beings. Romulans may be unaware of it, and unskilled in manipulating it, but they absolutely have one.

Comment: @LevenTrek - There's a body of evidence that suggests that not all sentient beings (humans, for example) have a Katra, nor is having one necessary to carry one; "*Amanda, unlike a Vulcan woman, had no future … at least, no future that was perceivable or verifiable. **As a human, she had not possessed a katra** … so nothing could be placed in the Hall of Ancient Thought, to linger until it was ready to go on to whatever lay next.*" - [TOS Novel: Sarek](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Sarek_(novel))

Comment: Respectfully, I don't see any evidence that contradicts the fact that all living beings have one. And the fact that Michael Burnham (a human) has one, and can use it, would seem to indicate the opposite. What am I missing?

Comment: @LevenTrek - She has part of Sarek's ***as a result of a mind-meld***. Basically a Horcrux

Comment: My last comment was before you edited your comment - that quote from the book is great. Nice

Comment: you're going to hate me for being so picky, but I'm pretty sure I found a quote that shows everyone has a katra (see my answer). I'm not going to edit your answer because that would be rude, but I think maybe the "they almost certainly don't have one" part is wrong